# heroku how to add more than one addon using heroku create command

Tags: heroku

tried

`heroku  create --stack cedar --remote testaddon    --addons loggly:mole  custom_domains`

and

`heroku  create --stack cedar --remote testaddon    --addons loggly:mole --addons custom_domains`

neither worked.

heroku help says

```
 heroku help create
Usage: heroku create [NAME]

 create a new app

     --addons ADDONS        # a list of addons to install
 -b, --buildpack BUILDPACK  # a buildpack url to use for this app
 -r, --remote REMOTE        # the git remote to create, default "heroku"
 -s, --stack STACK          # the stack on which to create the app
```

so seems that I should be able to install a list of addons. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried a comma-delimited list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list your add-ons in a comma delimited fashion:

```
heroku create --stack cedar --remote testaddon --addons loggly:mole, custom_domains
```